# Getting 404 Error when page obviously exists

Tags: python, python-requests

So I'm trying to make a POST Request but I'm getting a 404 Error. When I follow the link in my browser, it loads up just fine, but when I print the text for the POST response, all I get is a 404 page.

I've tried using Headers and have tried using an "Authenticity Token"

```py
atc = requests.post('https://www.saintalfred.com/cart/add.js', data = cart)
print(atc.text)

atc.cookies.get_dict()

r = requests.post("https://www.saintalfred.com/checkout", data=params, timeout = 20, cookies = atc.cookies)

print(r.text)

html = r.text

r.cookies.get_dict()


checkouttoken = re.search('DF_CHECKOUT_TOKEN = "(.*?)"', html)
authenticityToken = re.search('authenticity_token" value="(.*?)"',html)

print(checkouttoken.group(1))
print(authenticityToken.group(1))
aaaaa = checkouttoken.group(1).split('{fun')

aaaaaa = ''.join(aaaaa)

print(aaaaaa)

urlthing = "https://www.saintalfred.com/2681785/checkouts/" + aaaaaa + '?_method=patch&authenticity_token=' + authenticityToken.group(1)
print(urlthing)

headers = {'User Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3'}

z = requests.post(urlthing, data=params, timeout = 20, headers = headers, cookies = r.cookies)

print(z.text)
```

Expected: Not 404

Actual: 404 page.

Comment: 404 is HTTP Protocol status code, which means that resource is deleted. You can manipulate with status codes and return anything you want. For example 404 instead of 200. This is not problem. But in your case, maybe server checks headers and something is wrong and returned 404. This is more logical.

Comment: if you *follow the link in my browser,* it usually a `GET` not `POST`.

Comment: What @appleapple said. When you do it in a browser, the Saint Alfred site does a GET request to checkout. (If you're not logged in you get a perfectly valid 302).  Web servers handle get and post requests separately, and so 404 is expected here.

Comment: So how would I go about sending a request to submit the form?